# 2 buttons for mvc Website

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem when it comes to having 2 buttons on my web page. I want both buttons to import excel files, i have created the back end code to do so. I've managed to have the site display the 2 buttons however at the moment they both execute the same function whereas i would prefer it if the first button executes the MassImport method on the importcontroller and the second button executes the MassSPAImport. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My ViewModels for the 2 different import functions

```
namespace BLL.ViewModels.Import
{

        public class SPAMassImport
    {
        [Display(Name = "Mass Store Profile Allocation Data Import File (.csv)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase importFile { get; set; }
    }
}


    namespace BLL.ViewModels.Import
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ViewModel for Data Imports
    /// </summary>
    public class MassImport
    {
        [Display(Name = "Mass Import File (.csv)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase importFile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller that has the 2 different functions that i want to perform, however i believe only the first is being used by both buttons.

```
namespace PopFit.Areas.CustomerArea.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Controller for Data Imports
    /// </summary>
    [AuthAttribute]
    public class ImportController : Controller
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// Returns the index view
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns>ActionResult</returns>
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new MassImport());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// [HttpPost] Uploads and imports based on the MassImportDataDemo file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file">HttpPostedFileBase CSV file</param>
        /// <returns>ActionResult</returns>
        [HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult MassImport(MassImport vm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string type = vm.importFile.ContentType.ToLower().Trim();

                if (FileHelper.IsValidCsv(type))
                {
                    StoreImporter importer = new StoreImporter();                    
                    var result = importer.Import(vm.importFile);

                    switch (result)
                    {
                        case StoreImporterResult.FormatError:
                            //User needs to fix file format
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrectly Formatted File");
                            break;
                        case StoreImporterResult.StoreCreationSaveFailed:
                            //Database/System error
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed To Save Store Data, please contact an administrator.");
                            TempData["Failure"] = "Import Failed, Please Review Your File and Try Again.";
                            break;
                        case StoreImporterResult.WindowSurfaceDataError:
                            //Window Surface data is invalid, format needs to be corrected
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "There is an error with the Window Surface Data, please correct this and try again.");
                            TempData["Failure"] = "Import Failed, Please Review Your File and Try Again.";
                            break;
                        case StoreImporterResult.WindowSurfacesSaveFailed:
                            //Database/System error
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed To Save Window Surface Data, please contact an administrator.");
                            TempData["Failure"] = "Import Failed, Please Review Your File and Try Again.";
                            break;
                        case StoreImporterResult.ProfileAllocationSaveError:
                            //Database/System error
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to save Profile Item Data, please contact an administrator.");
                            TempData["Failure"] = "Import Failed, Please Review Your File and Try Again.";
                            break;
                        case StoreImporterResult.WindowItemAllocationSaveError:
                            //Database/System error
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to save Window Item Data, please contact an administrator.");
                            TempData["Failure"] = "Import Failed, Please Review Your File and Try Again.";
                            break;
                        default:
                            TempData["Success"] = "Import Successful";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "File must be a correctly formatted CSV");
                TempData["Failure"] = "Import Failed, Please Review Your File and Try Again.";
            }
            return View("Index", vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult MassSPAImport(MassImport vm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string type = vm.importFile.ContentType.ToLower().Trim();

                if (FileHelper.IsValidCsv(type))
                {
                    SPAStoreImporter importer = new SPAStoreImporter();
                    var result = importer.Import(vm.importFile);

                    switch (result)
                    {
                        case SPAStoreImporterResult.FormatError:
                            //User needs to fix file format
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrectly Formatted File");
                            break;
                        case SPAStoreImporterResult.ProfileAllocationSaveError:
                            //Database/System error
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to save Profile Item Data, please contact an administrator.");
                            TempData["Failure"] = "Import Failed, Please Review Your File and Try Again.";
                            break;
                        default:
                            TempData["Success"] = "Import Successful";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "File must be a correctly formatted CSV");
                TempData["Failure"] = "Import Failed, Please Review Your File and Try Again.";
            }
            return View("Index", vm);
        }
    }
}
```

My Index View

```
@using BLL.ViewModels.Import
@{ ViewBag.wrapClass = "admin-wrap"; } 
<div>
    <hgroup class="admin">
        <h2><i class="fa fa-lg fa-icon-for-pf-wrap"></i>Import.</h2>
    </hgroup>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("MassImport", "Import", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend">Mass Import Store Data</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.importFile)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field" title="Must be formatted as per Mass Import Document.">
                <input name="importFile" id="importFile" type="file" class="admin" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.importFile)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label"></div>
            <div class="submit-container">
                <input type="submit" value="Import" class="submit" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ColMassImport", "Import", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend">Mass Import Store Profile Allocation Data</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.importFile)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field" title="Must be formatted as per Mass Import Document.">
                <input name="importFile" id="importFile" type="file" class="admin" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.importFile)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label"></div>
            <div class="submit-container">
                <input type="submit" value="Import" class="submit" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }

    <div class="admin">
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to Administration", "AdminMenu", "Index", null, new { @class = "anchor-icon back" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the code, but you should really consider writing an [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't really sure what i could exclude so i thought it best to include most of what was needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you should be calling in the index view is MassSPAImport but you are calling ColMassImport, could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes it was, thank you very much, i had to rename some of my files and methods at one point so the refactor must have missed that, Thank you.